# Running a Junit test remotely, as if it were running locally, using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I've search around, read relevant questions on this site and others, but have failed to find a solution. It strikes me odd that one does not exist so let me detail my question here:

I use Junit4 + Eclipse regularly to test my code. In some cases, certain tests can take a lot of CPU and/or memory, rendering my workstation unusable for the duration of the test. This is a pain I'm trying to solve.

I'm looking to get the exact same behavior but through a remote server. I want:

1. To still be able to set breakpoints and debug my app.
2. To see how the tests progress using the Junit view in Eclipse.
3. Click on a button have the tests started (build process and copying of files is allowed, but only if efficient).

In my mind I envision something that rsyncs the files to the remote server, starts the java process there with the exact same arguments as it would on my local machine, makes the debug port available (not just localhost) and has eclipse hook up to it to have both debug and junit view working.

How can I get this done?

Several leading questions that may help us find a solution:

1. How does Eclipse communicate with the java process when run locally (for both debug purposes AND the Junit view)?
2. How can I involve myself in the process of spawning the java process for the JUnit testing so I can copy the required files over to a remote server?
3. How can I make the process spawn remotely instead of locally?
4. How can I have Eclipse hook up to the remote host instead of the localhost?

Comment: I'm also keeping my mind open to looking up the JUnit-plugin-for-eclipse code and branching off a solution if this is the last resort.

Comment: I understand that your motivation here is that your tests consume too much resources. Is it the tests or the code that is tested which slow down your machine? Are you running integrationtests with database setup and teardown around each test case?

Comment: The code that is tested is what slows down the machine. There's setup and tear down for each test class, which normally includes 10-15 tests.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest would be to invoke [command line JUnit runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_4) on remote mashine using the following command:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8998,server=y,suspend=y -cp ... org.junit.runner.JUnitCore <test class name>
```

So, it will wait til you attach remote debugger from Eclipse at port 8998.

You can also use Eclipse's [Target Management](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) tools to transfer files to remote system and launch remote commands. There is several tutorials on the project page.

Comment: How can I make it a seamless process where hitting a button in Eclipse will sync the code, start the java process and attach to it?

Comment: Are you talking about starting Java process on a remote host? I suppose you could write a script that you'll start using Eclipse's External Tool configuration (e.g. using ssh to launch remote commands). Then you could launch "Remote Java Application" launch configuration to attach to that remote process.

Comment: Is there a way to combine it all in one go?

Comment: There is always a way. But you will likely have to write your own Eclipse plugin. This is rather specific to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a jenkins CI server, sync your code via git (or just copy using ftp or something), execute the test in a jenkins job triggered by a git-hook or through some script. Then remote debug into the running test process like Eugene Kuleshov suggested. This process could be automated by an ant-script which you invoke from eclipse. There should be a mylin connector ([for example](https://tasktop.com/hudson)) through which you can monitor the running tests. I don't know if it is possible using the standard JUnit view of eclipse to see the running tests without using some custom plugins (if any exist).

Answer (score 0):

Try vs code remote ssh extension for this.